# How to use compiled bindings with BindingContext in Xamarin XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, compiled-bindings

I want to use `x:DataType` with `BindingContext` like below.

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:DataType="local:MainPageViewModel">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Label
        x:DataType="local:TitleViewModel"
        BindingContext ="{Binding InnerViewModel}" 
        Text="{Binding Title}" />

</ContentPage>
```

> Sorry @Jason, my previous mock code was too simplified to cause misleading.. Therefore I updated my mock code like below.

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    private TitleViewModel _innerViewModel;
    public TitleViewModel InnerViewModel
    {
        get => _innerViewModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _innerViewModel, value);
    }
}

public class TitleViewModel
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
}
```

---

The reason why I am not using `InnerViewModel.Title` for binding is `PropertyChanged` event only checks property path. So, If I update `InnerViewModel.Title`, it raise `PropertyChanged` event with path `"Title"`, not `"InnerViewModel.Title"`. It cause a problem.

I know I can do like below to solve,

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    private void OnInnerViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, "InnerViewModel.Title");
    }
}
```

But, I prefer to change `BindingContext` instead relaying `PropertyChanged` event.

---

However, it builds fail because of below reason.

> Error XFC0045: Binding: Property "InnerViewModel" not found on "Local.TitleViewModel".

Even if I delete `x:DataType` like below, still fail because MainPageViewModel does not have `Title` property.

```xml
<Label
    BindingContext ="{Binding InnerViewModel}"
    Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

Therefore, I give up to compiled bindings by using `x:null` like below.

```xml
<Label
    x:DataType="x:null"
    BindingContext ="{Binding InnerViewModel}" 
    Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

Comment: Can you add the ViewModel code? Also, why do you have soo many ViewModels? Adding your related VM code might help me understand the situation better

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `InnerViewModel` is not a property.  Further, (once you fix that problem) you can just use `"{Binding InnerViewModel.Title}" as the path, you don't need to specify the `BindingContext` again for the `Label`

Comment: @FreakyAli Umm.. Do you mean actual ViewModel code?

Comment: No, something that explains to me how it looks like a mock, Also Jason just answered your question

Comment: @ibocon Have you tried `public TitleViewModel InnerViewModel { get; }`?

Comment: Binding works fine. Only problem is compiled binding complains when build.

Comment: You can try to create a new class and use MainPageViewModel as its property to raise OnPropertyChanged("InnerViewModel").

Comment: @KyleWang-MSFT It is hard to imagine what you suggest. As far as I understand, what you suggest is`class NewViewModel { public MainPageViewModel { get; set; } public NewViewModel() { MainPageViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged; } private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (sender == MainPageViewModel) RaisePropertyChanged("InnerViewModel") } }` ?

Comment: Set the new class as the BindingContext. The new class contains a MainPageViewModel type property. And call "OnPropertyChanged" in "InnerViewModel set" `public TitleViewModel InnerViewModel { get => _innerViewModel; set { _innerViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("InnerViewModel"); }}`.